# Tap water conductivity differences between AC and DC

Tags: electricity, water, conductors

Direct current is often used in electrolysis and because of the alternating nature of AC, it's not great for electrolysis. Tap water, however, conducts AC really well.

But why is that? Why does alternating current flow through water well following the Ohm's law and why does DC act like a diode; water passes DC through after a certain voltage point and from there on it conducts it just fine?

Comment: Do you have some reference to document these observations? For example, the current versus voltage in DC and AC.

Comment: *Homogeneous* water even with if an electrolyte surely does not act as a diode for a diode conducts differently upon polarity change of bias (at least this the conventional definition of what a diode is). All diodes (vacuum or solids-state) are *materially* asymmetrical and that manifests in their electric behavior.

Comment: @nasu Only my own measurements which should represent the effect. They might not be really accurate given the equipment used. https://i.gyazo.com/9d39a1afb1239ad9c5347fedc0bae683.png

Comment: @hyportnex My physics professor compared the effect to a diode, however. Neither was I convinced it works that way, but the measurements I took linked above, show that DC doesn't flow similarly to AC.

Comment: You seem to be measuring in 100V steps; what was the dc current meter quantization, ie. smallest change on the readout? To prove that is not a quantization error you should dither the bias. Anyhow, to show diode-like behavior you would have to reverse the bias voltage and current and see what it does.

Comment: For the AC regime you will have a current even if you have nothing (air) between electrodes.  Have you tried to estimate the capacitive reactance of your setup? I mean, pure water is a good dielectric so a capacitor filled with water may have significant capacitance.

Comment: @hyportnex Seemingly there is an error in my spreadsheet. The unit should be millivolts. Maybe we should leave this data aside and just focus on _what ought to happen_. So, what are the fundamental differences in the current flow in water between AC and DC?